# Wandering Trader Spawning?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

The [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Wandering_Trader) says that every 20 minutes the wandering trader has a 7.5% chance of spawning within 48 blocks of the player, but:

- Does the normal "not within 24 blocks of spawn point" rule apply?
- Does he only spawn on opaque, full blocks?
- Can the odds be increased by making multiple layers he can spawn on?
- How is it determined whether the player is "underground"?
- How does it work differently in multiplayer?  The wiki just says "the player"

Comment: Honestly, this might require more testing before anyone knows. This feature is kinda new.

Comment: The wiki already says that it's any player, so that answers your last question: It picks one at random. And there's actually a way to lock it for you, so that it never spawns for anyone else ever again. But I won't say publicly how. ;) Also, I'll do some spawning tests today anyway, I'll just add the wandering trader to that list of tests.

Comment: You have to wait an average of 3 hours before the first wandering trader spawns in a world.

Comment: Over night I did a first spawn test: I made a new default world, made sure that a lot of chunks around spawn were loaded, stood around AFK in Creative and had a command system tell me when there is or ever was a wandering trader. It took about 3.5 hours until there was one and it did not despawn or walk very far in the next ~30 minutes. Then I started a new test, a 100x100 platform of stone at height 128 in a void superflat taiga (because I need that test for my own project anyway). 3.5 hours later he has not spawned yet, but the probability for that was just ~55%, so I'll continue waiting.

Comment: I was stupid and forgot that it snows and things don't spawn on snow. I cleared the snow, set the weather to permanently clear and a few minutes later a wandering trader spawned. So that works.

Comment: It does not seem to care about being too close to the player when spawning. Spawning on snow seems to be impossible, so I assume it has the regular spawning rules (opaque block, air space, …).

Comment: @FabianRöling, any chance of turning these excellent comments into an answer?  These mechanics are still not well understood it seems, but this is the best write up I've found.

Comment: There are still very many things I don't understand about it, for example one recently spawned next to me inside a building. Slabs seem to probably stop it from spawning, but I'm not sure. It doesn't usually spawn in caves, so maybe solid blocks above prevent it. Or maybe not. I also don't know if it ever despawns, what happens if it gets unloaded, etc. This question is on my "to figure out later" list, so I will definitely get to it some day.

Comment: The real answer to this question is: It's complicated and buggy. There are currently 20 open bug reports for the search terms "wandering trader spawn".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Does the normal "not within 24 blocks of spawn point" rule apply?

   Yes.
- Does he only spawn on opaque, full blocks?

   Yes.
- Can the odds be increased by making multiple layers he can spawn on?

   No.
- How is it determined whether the player is "underground"?

   This doesn't have relevance, but it's based on a mixture of factors which I don't know. I believe it's being inside the "cave" generation chunks.
- How does it work differently in multiplayer? The wiki just says "the player".

   It picks a random player to spawn it near.

Comment: "Does the normal 'not within 24 blocks of spawn point' rule apply? Yes." What did you base that on? I'm pretty sure that in my experiments wandering traders spawned very close to me, as well as on a (Bukkit) Survival server. And the other answer also says that.

Comment: 24 blocks from spawn point is not 24 blocks from player.

Comment: Oh sorry, I read that wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Wandering traders can spawn anywhere within 48 blocks of the player. I once had one spawn about 3 blocks away from me.