# How could I make a spawn platform for wandering traders in order to get Nautilus shells?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I need Nautilus shells quickly, and I think wandering traders are the best option. Problem is, wandering traders are kind of annoying to find.

I was thinking of making a spawn platform to AFK on and check back every so often. How big should it be? Should it be high off the ground?

Comment: Drowned are a better way to get them. There are various Drowned farm designs online, but I don't think any wandering trader farms. There is a bit of info on wandering trader spawning [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/350642/171580), but it's probably still missing quite a few things. Do I understand it right that this question is essentially "how to build a wandering trader farm"?

Answer (score 1):

An AFK fish farm is a dead easy way to get Nautilus shells. Just AFK overnight and you'll get loads of them. Before you do, make sure you have enough storage space for the items to automatically feed into!

Follow Xisumavoids tutorial for a visual walkthrough:

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: This farm will no longer produce nautilus shells or any 'treasure loot' as of .1.16.1. There are designs that work, but at much worse efficiency and much more complex. (otherwise, this farm is fine for fish and 'junk' loot like lillypads.)

Answer (score 0):

Well there might be a easy way to get them from drowned. First try to illuminate the waters nearby so there are going to be no drowned automatically spawning. I recommend glow stone,or if you can’t, use torches and glass. Secondly, build a small hut which's interior is pitch black. The drowned will spawn there, and you can put a villager in another small hut underwater so the drowned are attracted to it. Then put cactus in front of the hut’s only entrance, so the drowned will receive damage from the cacti. Items float in water, so all you need is to afk above water so the items automatically float towards you. Hope this might help.